# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA, Hibernate and MySQL

and I am getting following exception

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_payment_request")
public class Request implements Serializable {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Long id;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "request",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     private List<PaymentItem> paymentItems;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "my_payment_item")
public class PaymentItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "request_id", nullable=true)
    private Request request;

}

public class Manager {
Request request = new Request();
    List<PaymentItem> paymentItems = new ArrayList<PaymentItem>();
        PaymentItem paymentItem1 = new PaymentItem();
        paymentItem1.setRequest(request);
        PaymentItem paymentItem2 = new PaymentItem();
        paymentItem2.setRequest(request);
        paymentItems.add(paymentItem1);
        paymentItems.add(paymentItem2);
        request.setPaymentItems(paymentItems);

}
```

> Hibernate code

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        request.setId((Long) session.save(request));
        session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do with `request.setId((Long) session.save(request))`?

Comment: I do not see there you do `request.setPaymentItems(paymentItems);`

Comment: @guido I had forgotten to put that line in this question but its there in my actual code

Comment: You're trying to save a value in foreign key which doesn't exist in its referenced primary key field..

Comment: @ankit in this case, i guess you need to save the two paymentItems first, then `setRequest(request)` on both, then you can save the request.

Comment: @guido cascade.ALL will take care of it

Comment: @ankit but the direction of the relation is the other, and request is nullable in paymentitem

Comment: Do you get any further info as to which constraint has failed? I suspect by putting a snippet of the code above, you've missed something important as the code above should work fine.

Answer (score -2):

Turn this off by adding this before the insert command:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

then set it back after your inserts:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Just make sure you know what you are doing.